# How to connect Oracle 11G database using SQL developer from another computer in a LAN connection

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, listener, remote-connection

I am very new in database and learning Oracle 11G. So, I do not have deep knowledge on it.

I have several computers in my lab connected via LAN. Oracle 11G is installed in computer-A(192.18.100.115). Now I want to use the database from other computers in my Lab via SQL Developer that is installed into all Computers.

Would you please explain

1. What I need to do in Computer-A for granting access from other Computers?
2. What I need to do in other computers for getting access from computer-A?

I will be grateful if any one gives me a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. What I need to do in Computer-A for granting access from other Computers?

You need to make sure the **LISTENER** is up and running to accept remote connection requests. **Listener.ora** is a SQL*Net configuration file used to configure Oracle Database Listeners. You will usually find that in `ORACLE_HOME\NETWORK\ADMIN` directory.

For example,

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))
      )
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ORCL)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0)
      (SID_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )
```

As you mentioned your host `192.18.100.115`, you need to put it in the **hostname**.

> 2. What I need to do in other computers for getting access from computer-A?

You just need to install **Oracle database client**. If you only want to connect to the remote DB server, you could install only **Instant client**.

If you are using SQL Developer, then you could use:

- **Basic connection type**

Or,

- **TNS connection type**

In basic connection type, you need to provide all the connection details in the connection properties itself. For using TNS connection type, you need to configure the **tnsnames.ora** file present in `ORACLE_HOME\NETWORK\ADMIN` directory.

Comment: How do I check whether LISTENER is running accurately?

Comment: @AnawarParvez Please mark it as answered, would help others.